# regular expression to convert state names to abbreviations

Tags: regex, states, abbreviation

I'm working on a project that requires only the use of regular expression to convert state names (must be case insensitive) to their two letter abbreviations.

I cannot use any sort of development environment or link to any databases or xml or ini files.

Please help!

Comment: There are only 51 states, 51 abreviations, all arbitrary. Its usually the first 2 letters on a single word state, double word state, its the first letter of each word. But there are exceptions.

Comment: That is a bizarre and nonsensical requirement - can you explain more about why you need to solve the problem in this way?

Answer (score 2):

Since states don't have something *regular* in them *regular expressions* is the **WRONG** tool. I would suggest getting a new project.

However, the only solution (apart from stupid illogical hacks) is to hardcore every state:

```
s/Alabama/Al/
s/Alaska/Ak/
...
s/Wyoming/Wy/
```

A list of the states and their abbreviations can be found [here](http://www.usps.com/ncsc/lookups/abbr_state.txt).