# Convert long state names embedded with other text to two-letter state abbreviations

Tags: r, regex

My objective is to identify US states written out in a character vector that has other text and convert the states to abbreviated form.  For example, "North Carolina" to "NC".  It is simple if the vector only has long-form state names.  However, my vector has other text in random places, as in the example "states".

```
states <- c("Plano New Jersey", "NC", "xyz", "Alabama 02138", "Texas", "Town Iowa 99999")
```

From another post I found this:

```
state.abb[match(states, state.name)]
```

but it converts only the standalone Texas

```
> state.abb[match(states, state.name)]
[1] NA   NA   NA   NA   "TX"
```

and not the New Jersey, Alabama and Iowa strings.

From [Fast grep with a vectored pattern or match, to return list of all matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877290/efficiency-effort-grep-with-a-vectored-pattern-or-match-with-a-list-of-values) I tried:

```
sapply(states, grep(pattern = state.name, x = states, value = TRUE))
```

but

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'Alabama 02138' of mode 'function' was not found
In addition: Warning message:
In grep(pattern = state.name, x = states, value = TRUE) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Nor does this work:

```
sapply(states, function(x) state.abb[grep(state.name, states)])
```

This question did not help:
[regular expression to convert state names to abbreviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598214/regular-expression-to-convert-state-names-to-abbreviations)

How do I convert the embedded long names to the state abbreviation?

EDIT: I want to return the vector with the only change being that the long names of the states have been abbreviated, e.g., "Plano New Jersey" becomes "Plano NJ".

Thank you for correcting and/or educating me.

Comment: You might get 'NY, NY' out of this, plus there are towns called 'California' as well as states.  However, that's nitpicking for you.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler:  yes, towns called states is an occupational hazard.  Plus I have cities that are in more than one state.  Sigh.  Why can't data behave nicely?

Comment: There's this thing called 'The Real World'™ that you should visit sometime ("Dear Kettle — you're black!  Signed, Pot").  It has a nasty habit of diverging from the tidy schemes that those of us who write programs devise.

Comment: Might be good to search the web for a table of "City, STATE" names and read it into R to do the matching.

Comment: @RichardScriven: Good point.  I found 394 of such city, ST matches on Wikipedia, created a data frame and can use that also.  I am still struggling to allocate Columbus, for example, since there are cities of that name in several states.

Comment: You could create a by-state list of each city-state combination if you can find all 50 states somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
library(qdap)
mgsub(state.name, state.abb, states)

## [1] "Plano NJ"      "NC"            "xyz"           "AL 02138"      
## "TX"            "Town IA 99999"
```

If you are uncertain that the states will be capitalized you may want to use:

```
mgsub(state.name, state.abb, states, ignore.case=TRUE, fixed=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
indx <- paste0(".*(", paste(state.name, collapse="|"), ").*")
v1 <- gsub(indx, "\\1", states)
ifelse( v1 %in% state.abb, v1, state.abb[match(v1, state.name)])
#[1] "NJ" "NC" NA   "AL" "TX" "IA"
```

If you want to just replace the states with the abbreviation and not the other text, you could also do:

```
indx1 <- paste(state.name, collapse="|")   
indx2 <- state.abb[match(v1, state.name)]

mapply(gsub, indx1, indx2, states, USE.NAMES=F)
#[1] "Plano NJ"      "NC"            "xyz"           "AL 02138"     
#[5] "TX"            "Town IA 99999"
```

Comment: I noticed that this replaces each matching state with the abbreviation of the state which comes first in the alfabet. For example, the input `"Texas Alabama"` will result in `"AL AL"`. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @EricBouwers In the example the OP provided, it was not the case.  So, I didn't check it that way

Answer (score 1):

It was not clear from the question what the expected result is to be but here we have assumed that you want to preserve the text in the input just replacing the fuil state names with the abbreviation.

Create a list, `st`, whose names are the full state names and whose values are the abbreviations.  Then use `paste(..., collapse = "|")` to create a regular expression that matches any state and use `gsubfn` from the gsubfn package to perform the substitutions.

```
library(gsubfn)
st <- as.list(setNames(state.abb, state.name))
gsubfn(paste(state.name, collapse = "|"), st, states)
```

giving:

```
[1] "Plano NJ"      "NC"            "xyz"           "AL 02138"     
[5] "TX"            "Town IA 99999"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use additional packages you can use the [mapply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mapply.html) function to apply `gsub` for all pairs of `state.name` and `state.abb`, e.g.:

```
mapply(gsub,state.name,state.abb,"ALABAMA 123",ignore.case=TRUE,USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

The result of this is a list which could contain a replacement, e.g.:

```
 [1] "AL 123"      "ALABAMA 123" "ALABAMA 123" "ALABAMA 123" "ALABAMA 123" 
 [6] ...
```

by taking the shortest text from this list you can get the desired result. Thus we [sort the list based on the length of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325719/r-base-function-to-sort-vector-of-strings-based-on-length) and take the first element.

The complete code:

```
replaceState <- function(x) {  
     v = mapply(gsub,state.name,state.abb,x,ignore.case=TRUE, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
     v[order(nchar(v))][1] 
}

sapply(states, replaceState, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

Unfortunately, this approach only replaces the name of a single state (the longest). To replace multiple different states we need to iterate, e.g.:

```
replaceState <- function(x) {  
     v = mapply(gsub,state.name,state.abb,x,ignore.case=TRUE, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
     v[order(nchar(v))][1] 
}

replaceStates <- function(x) {
     newX = replaceState(x)

     # if they are different a state has been replaced, 
     # we try again to replace all states.
     if(newX != x){ 
          replaceStates(newX)
     } else {
          newX
     }
}

# Note the 'replaceStates'
sapply(states, replaceStates, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for(r in 1:nrow(states.list)) {
    states = gsub(states.list[r,1], states.list[r,2], states)
}

states
[1] "Plano NJ"      "NC"            "xyz"           "AL 02138"      "TX"            "Town IA 99999"
```

Data:

```
states <- c("Plano New Jersey", "NC", "xyz", "Alabama 02138", "Texas", "Town Iowa 99999")

states.list = structure(list(state.name = structure(c(4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Iowa", "Minnesota", "New Jersey", "Texas"), class = "factor"), 
    state.abb = structure(c(4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("AL", 
    "IA", "MN", "NJ", "TX"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("state.name", 
"state.abb"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

states.list
  state.name state.abb
1 New Jersey        NJ
2    Alabama        AL
3      Texas        TX
4       Iowa        IA
5  Minnesota        MN
```