# How to convert this 'for' loop to a vector solution

Tags: r

This question is related to: [Convert long state names embedded with other text to two-letter state abbreviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582518/convert-long-state-names-embedded-with-other-text-to-two-letter-state-abbreviati)

Following for loop code works well.

```
for(r in 1:nrow(states.list)) {
    states = sub(states.list[r,1], states.list[r,2], states)
}

states
[1] "Plano NJ"      "NC"            "xyz"           "AL 02138"      "TX"            "Town IA 99999"
```

Data:

```
states <- c("Plano New Jersey", "NC", "xyz", "Alabama 02138", "Texas", "Town Iowa 99999")

states.list = structure(list(state.name = structure(c(4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Iowa", "Minnesota", "New Jersey", "Texas"), class = "factor"), 
    state.abb = structure(c(4L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("AL", 
    "IA", "MN", "NJ", "TX"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("state.name", 
"state.abb"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

states.list
  state.name state.abb
1 New Jersey        NJ
2    Alabama        AL
3      Texas        TX
4       Iowa        IA
5  Minnesota        MN
```

I tried following to have a vector solution, but they do not work:

```
apply(states.list, 1, function(x) {
    sapply(states, function(y) {
        sub(   x[1], x[2],   y
        )
        })
})

sapply(states, function(x) sub(states.list[,1], states.list[,2], x))

apply(states.list, 1, function(x) sub(x[1],x[2], states))
```

How can I convert it to a vector solution (using apply etc, without using any special packages)?  Thanks for your help.

Edit: 
output of akrun's solution:

```
sapply ( seq_len(nrow(states.list)), function(i) {
+ sub(states.list[i,1], states.list[i,2], states[i])
+ })
[1] "Plano NJ"      "NC"            "xyz"           "Alabama 02138" "Texas"
```

Comment: @ akrun: It does not produce correct output. See edit in my question.

Comment: @mso Oops, I didn't check it.

Comment: @ akrun: let your solution stay as it may give some idea to someone else. If you wish I will delete it.

Comment: @mso It is okay to stay there.

Comment: Use of `*apply` is not a "vector solution" .  `for` loops run about as fast as `apply` in any case; if you want a truly vectorized solution, it can't include `apply`.

Comment: As 'for' loops are discouraged in R, I want to use other base functions for this apparently simple problem.

Comment: @mso  That's an urban legend.  Loops are only discouraged when vectorized methods are applicable. And as we're all telling you,  `apply` **is** a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this can be vectorized. At best you can hide the `for` loop under an `*apply` equivalent, or using `Reduce` like here:

```
ARGS <- split(states.list, seq_len(nrow(states.list)))
FUN  <- function(x, y) gsub(as.character(y$state.name),
                            as.character(y$state.abb), x)
Reduce(FUN, ARGS, states)
```

It's fancy and all but it is IMHO not worth the effort: it is probably not faster than a `for` loop and it is much harder to understand, isn't it? There's a little too much stigma around using `for` in R.

Comment: Exactly my view.  Stick with the `for` loop, and if desired, use `compile` to make a faster function.